# Making JQuery slideshow iterate only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I want to make a slideshow of pictures switching every two seconds, and I have this code.

HTML:

```
<div class="fadeIn">
    <img src="img/city.png" class="remimg" id="city">
    <img src="img/shop.png" class="remimg" id="shop">
    <img src="img/ice-cream-cone.png" class="remimg" id="icecream">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('.fadeIn img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.fadeIn :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.fadeIn');}, 
        2000);
});
```

How do I make it only iterate once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a counter, assign the interval to a variable, and then clear the interval.

[Here's a Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/aoLy57g4/)

Modify your javascript like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('.fadeIn img:gt(0)').hide();
    // assign this to a variable, since we're going to check it often
    var total = $('.fadeIn img').length;
    // initialize the counter
    // You can adjust this number as desired.  
    // For example, set it to 0 if you want the show to end on the first slide
    var count = 1;
    // assign the interval to a variable so we can clear it
    var slideInterval = setInterval(function() {
        // if the current slide count is equal to or greater than the total slides, clear the interval
        if (++count >= total) {
            // stops the slideInterval (and therefore the slideshow)
            clearInterval(slideInterval);
            // You could do other things here if desired....
        }
        $('.fadeIn :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.fadeIn');}, 
        2000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to use a recursive function without appending the images, and then just stop when the last image is reached

```
$(function() {
    var all   = $('.fadeIn img'),
        first = all.first(),
        last  = all.last();

    all.not(first).hide();

    (function fn(image) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var f = image.fadeOut().next().fadeIn();
            if ( f.get(0) !== last.get(0)  ) fn(f);
        }, 2000);
    }(first));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8apd8eeg/2/)